# Create two new data frames from two existing data frames, taking into account all combinations of their multi-index columns and their values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, combinatorics

I want to create two new data frames from two existing data frames, taking into account all combinations of their multi-index columns and their values.

```
left = pd.DataFrame(([1,0,1], [1,0,0],[1,0,1],), columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C' ), ('D','D'),]))
right = pd.DataFrame(([8,9], [8,9],[8,9],), columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('S', 'T'), ('Y', 'Z'),]))
```

###### left:

```
   A  A  D
   B  C  D
0  1  0  1
1  1  0  0
2  1  0  1
```

###### right:

```
   S  Y
   T  Z
0  8  9
1  8  9
2  8  9
```

###### expected output

###### left_result:

```
   A  A  A  A  D  D
   B  B  C  C  D  D
0  1  1  0  0  1  1
1  1  1  0  0  0  0
2  1  1  0  0  1  1
```

###### right_result:

```
   S  Y  S  Y  S  Y
   T  Z  T  Z  T  Z
0  8  9  8  9  8  9
1  8  9  8  9  8  9
2  8  9  8  9  8  9
```

*PS: Sorry if my question is not precise enough, but the example with the expected result still explains it best without words. Perhaps the question has already been asked, but in the absence of a precise description of what kind of result I actually want (combination in two DataFrames?), I ask you to help formulate the question more precisely or to link it as a duplicate if an existing question is present.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use [`MultiIndex.from_product`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) based on the [flat index](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.to_flat_index.html) of each DataFrame then [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) based on the corresponding [level values](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html):

```
midx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([left.columns.to_flat_index(),
                                   right.columns.to_flat_index()])

left = left.reindex(columns=midx.get_level_values(0))
right = right.reindex(columns=midx.get_level_values(1))
```

`left`:

```
   A           D   
   B  B  C  C  D  D
0  1  1  0  0  1  1
1  1  1  0  0  0  0
2  1  1  0  0  1  1
```

`right`:

```
   S  Y  S  Y  S  Y
   T  Z  T  Z  T  Z
0  8  9  8  9  8  9
1  8  9  8  9  8  9
2  8  9  8  9  8  9
```

---

`midx` for reference:

```
MultiIndex([(('A', 'B'), ('S', 'T')),
            (('A', 'B'), ('Y', 'Z')),
            (('A', 'C'), ('S', 'T')),
            (('A', 'C'), ('Y', 'Z')),
            (('D', 'D'), ('S', 'T')),
            (('D', 'D'), ('Y', 'Z'))],
           )
```

Note: level 0 are the `left` flat index values and level 1 are the `right` flat index values.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html?highlight=reindex#pandas.DataFrame.reindex) + [`Index.repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html?highlight=index%20repeat#pandas.Index.repeat) on the columns (`axis=1`)

```
# repeat 'left' columns 2 times 
>>> left = left.reindex(left.columns.repeat(2), axis=1)
>>> left

   A           D   
   B  B  C  C  D  D
0  1  1  0  0  1  1
1  1  1  0  0  0  0
2  1  1  0  0  1  1

# repeat 'right' columns 3 times 
>>> right = right.reindex(right.columns.repeat(3), axis=1)
>>> right 

   S        Y      
   T  T  T  Z  Z  Z
0  8  8  8  9  9  9
1  8  8  8  9  9  9
2  8  8  8  9  9  9
```

Or [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html?highlight=concat#pandas.concat)

```
# concatenate 'right' 3 times side by side (axis=1)
>>> right = pd.concat([right]*3, axis=1)
>>> right

   S  Y  S  Y  S  Y
   T  Z  T  Z  T  Z
0  8  9  8  9  8  9
1  8  9  8  9  8  9
2  8  9  8  9  8  9
```